# Jump to a Top level function if error in sub level function and return flag python

Tags: python

I have a function "main_func" , from which i am calling another function and so on.

```
class Error(Exception):
   """Base class for other exceptions"""
   pass

def main_func():
    return sub_func()

def sub_func():
    return sub_sub_func()

def sub_sub_func():
    return sub_sub_sub_func()

def sub_sub_sub_func():
    try:
        x = len(10)
        res = 'b'
    except:
        raise Error
    return res

main_func()
```

If you see in `sub_sub_sub_func()` i have added a line `x = len(10)` which will cause exception.

What i want is, if this happens, i should directly jump to main_func() and return a `flag(str) as 'fail'`

I looked into defining custom exceptions , but it didn't helped me.

I want to return after i raise.

Comment: Did you mean add a `try-except` in `main_func()`?

Comment: @endless no not using try except, using raise

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "jump". Currently, your raising the exception will make you code "jump" for none of the intermediate "sub" functions implement any form of exception handling.

Comment: What is `flag(str)`? If you want go to `main_func`, maybe you have to use `return` or idk, [`yield`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html?#yield-expressions)?

Answer (score 1):

`len(10)` will raise a `TypeError` you can catch this specific exception in your `main_func` and do the thing that needs to happen then.

Please note that you need to create an instance of your error class when raising. `Error()`

```
class Error(Exception):
    """Base class for other exceptions"""
    pass

def main_func():
    try:
        return sub_func()
    except (Error as e):
        # The raised error will be cought here.
        # Do the stuff that needs to happen here.
        return 'fail'

def sub_func():
    return sub_sub_func()

def sub_sub_func():
    return sub_sub_sub_func()

def sub_sub_sub_func():
    try:
        x = len(10) # Will raise a `TypeError`
        res = 'b'
    except:
        # `TypeError` that is raised will get here
        raise Error()
    return res

main_func()
```

Note: Your custom `Error` hides a lot of information that can come in handy later. What happened what raised this error. Best is to put the original `TypeError` as an inner exception to `Error`.

```
try:
    x = len(10)
except Throwable as e:
    raise Error(e)
```

In theory in your code a potential out of memory exception will be converted to your Error without knowing what happened.